# Specific order for multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a multidimensional associative array containing more than 2 columns.

I am trying to create a function that orders the array with the value of two specific columns. For example if value_column_3 ('hangs_from') from position 4 in the array depends from value_column_1 ('old_id') from position 0 in the array, I have to move position 4 of the array right after position 0.

It's sort of bubble sort algorithm.

How can I access and specific position from this multidimensional associative array so I can do the comparison?

Comment: check uasort : https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_uasort.asp

Comment: but how do you compare specifically the fifth and sixth position for example? I mean for example trying to use the bubble sort using:
  for(i=2; i<count(array); i++){
    for(j=0; j<count(array)-1; j++){
       if(array(position i) > array(position j));
          ...something
    }
  }

Comment: where array for the key 1038 gone in the last desired array ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy sorry I missed that value

Comment: one more thing why array for key 1034 after the 1037 as 1034 comes first in the array ?

Comment: if you need to sort by key then follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183575/access-array-key-using-uasort-in-php

Comment: @BunkerBoy because it's like having a 3 level menu:
  - old_id 1
  - - old_id 1030
  - - old_id 1031
  - - - old_id 1037
  - - old_id 1034
  - - old_id 1038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
$sortedArray = [];
foreach($q1 as $key => $value){
    $tempData = [];
    foreach($q1 as $key2 => $value2){
        if($value2['hangs_from'] === $key){
            $tempData[$value2['old_id']] = $value2;
            unset($q1[$value2['old_id']]);
        }
    }
    uasort($tempData, function($a, $b){
        return ($a['old_id'] < $b['old_id']) ? -1 : 1;
    });
    $sortedArray[$key] = $value;
    unset($q1[$value['old_id']]);
    $sortedArray = $sortedArray + $tempData;
}
```